# Add "ALL" option as 1st Selection Of Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am in need of adding in the ALL option as the top choice of a combobox.  I have tried this code below, but All is not addded, what must I alter in order to have that added?

```
string query = "select [empname] from [server].[dbo].[table]";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "tables");
cbotables.DisplayMember = "empname";
cbotables.Items.Insert(0, "All");
cbotables.DataSource = ds.Tables["tables"];
```

**EDIT**
I just realized a few things were not showing in my code...my connection string is declared above, and the contents of the combobox display as they should from the database, just no ALL option added.

Comment: You cant use a datasource and stuff things in `Items` manually

Comment: @Plutonix - is there a "band-aid" for this?  I.E. should I add the items to a data table then add ALL to the data table, or could I insert the items into a New SQL Table and insert ALL at the top of that list, then pull the data from the newly created table?

Comment: *Usually* with a datasource you'd want a valuemember as well (like the Emp Id).  Since you are just after the name, why use a datasource?  Use addrange and a linq 1 liner to add the names to the items collection

Comment: ...you could also add a row to the datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way would be to Insert a row into the `DataTable` assuming its only role is to be a `DataSource`:

```
// fill the datatable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

var dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Id"] = -1;
dr["Name"] = "All";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

cboEmp.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboEmp.ValueMember = "Id";
cboEmp.DataSource = dt;
```

It is more common to have a `ValueMember` with these so you can tell what was selected, thus the "Id" column.  If the `DataTable` has other purposes you may not want to add fake data to it.  For that, you could transfer the data to an anonymous list:

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

// xfer data to anon collection
var myDS = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(q => new {Name = q.Field<String>("Name"),
                      Value = q.Field<Int32>("Id") }
           )
    .ToList();

// add ALL with fake id
myDS.Insert(0, new { Name = "ALL", Value = -1 });

cboEmp.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboEmp.ValueMember = "Value";
cboEmp.DataSource = myDS;
```

Either way gets the same results:

[image]

If you truly dont need the `Id`, you dont need an anon type and can just select the name and a `List<string>`

Comment: Work well with comboBoxes manipulated with `SqlClient.DataTables`. Bravo